# Curiously recurring template patterm: double inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, crtp

I have the following:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    std::string _name;

public:
    virtual ~Base(){}

    const std::string &name;

    Base()
        : _name ("(no name)")
        , name(_name)
    {}
};

template <typename T>
class BaseH : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseH() {}
    BaseH() : Base() {}

    T& operator~(){ ; return static_cast<T&>(*this);}
};

class One : public BaseH<One>
{
public:
    One() : BaseH<One>() { _name = "One"; }

};

class Two
    : public One
    , public BaseH<Two>
{
public:
    Two() : BaseH<Two>() { _name = "Two"; }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << Two().name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to derive `Two` from both `One` and `BaseH<Two>`, because `Two` is a specialization of `One`, and the `operator~` in `BaseH` must always return a reference of the type of the object that's calling it.

Compilation errors are obviously:

```
In constructor ‘Two::Two()’:
  error: reference to ‘_name’ is ambiguous
  error: candidates are: std::string Base::_name
  error:                 std::string Base::_name
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  error: request for member ‘name’ is ambiguous
  error: candidates are: const string& Base::name
  error:                 const string& Base::name
```

How do I make `_name` and `name` accessible in both `One` and `Two`, while setting the `const` references via constructor delegation? What is the cleanest way to do that?

Comment: I doubt if this is really a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Or at least by having `virtual` function, you are not taking advantage of it.

Comment: @iammilind: not sure what you mean, but for what it's worth, this is of course a tiny excerpt from the "real" code

Comment: CRTP is typically useful when you want to eliminate the overhead caused due to `virtual` function (see the wiki link). In the code example, it's not taking advantage of it. May be what you have posted is another form of CRTP.

Comment: @iammilind: do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish the above otherwise?

Comment: From your code, I don't see any need of `virtual` destructor in any class, because you are using CRTP. If you are allocating memory to `BaseH<T>*` with `new T`/`delete pT` then may be some tweaks are needed. But that has to be discussed in detail and it's worth another question. You can also mention your design goal such as what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've got the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).  Have you tried [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)?

e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseH : virtual public Base
{
    // ...
};

class One : virtual public BaseH<One>
{
    // ...
};
```

edit: further reading on the diamond problem here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

Comment: See, I *knew* I had seen this problem before :) Thanks, works now.

Comment: Another of C++'s quirks.  No problem :)